# Error: "Zend Optimizer Not installed"

Tags: php

I got this error despite having Zend Optimizer installed.

> Zend Optimizer not installed.In order to run it, please install the freely available Zend Optimizer, version 2.1.0 or later.

I use PHP Version 5.2.5:

> Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2007 Zend Technologies
>   with Zend Extension Manager v1.2.0, Copyright (c) 2003-2007, by Zend Technologies
>   with Zend Optimizer v3.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2007, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Are you running in cli or through a webserver? They might use different php versions or ini's

Comment: i would be gratefull if anyone could give a solution to the above mentioned issue

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you don't have an include path set up that would pull in Zend Optimizer. You could try adding the following code to your php.ini (or .htaccess, if necessary):

```
<IfModule php5_module>
  php_value include_path 'include path here';
</IfModule>
```

See http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?id=2481 for a little more detail.